# Azure pipeline run status queued

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am new to Azure environment. i have written some code using .net core that starts Azure pipeline using Azure Data factory. The status of the pipeline run status when trying from my local is always success. I deployed the code in the azure environment. When try to start the pipe line from azure server always the status is queued. what is queued status and what i have to do with it. can some one please help. do i need to change any settings in azure so that the pipeline run will be success

```
            AuthenticationContext context = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/" + tenantID);
            ClientCredential cc = new ClientCredential(applicationId, authenticationKey);
            AuthenticationResult result = context.AcquireTokenAsync("https://management.azure.com/", cc).Result;
            ServiceClientCredentials cred = new TokenCredentials(result.AccessToken);
            var client = new Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataFactory.DataFactoryManagementClient(cred) { SubscriptionId = subscriptionId };

            CreateRunResponse runResponse = client.Pipelines.CreateRunWithHttpMessagesAsync(resourceGroup, dataFactoryName, pipelineName).Result.Body;
            string RunId = runResponse.RunId;
            PipelineRun pipelineRun;
            while (true)
            {
                pipelineRun = client.PipelineRuns.Get(resourceGroup, dataFactoryName, runResponse.RunId);
                if (pipelineRun.Status == "InProgress")
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(15000);
                else
                    break;
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

You should try to look into the diagnotics logs of the IR , it does have valuable info which should help .

Navigate to IR -> diagnotics log or open event viewer -> Application and service logs ->